# Create resources using multiple Terraform providers (GCP and Kubernetes) in the same TF script

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, google-kubernetes-engine, terraform-provider-gcp, terraform-provider-kubernetes

I'm new to Terraform.

I am trying to:

1. Create a Kubernetes cluster in GCP (GKE) ***using Terraform***
2. Deploy a K8s deployment to the same cluster ***using Terraform***

How can I process to create a new cluster on GCP, and deploy some service on the cluster just created?

Answer (score 0):

You should use first provider with `host`, `token` and `ca_certificate`.

The one with `config_path` will use config from your host, so will try to run kubernetes provider using your user, not terraform service account.

Provider configuration looks good, I use same and it works.

Do you set up single cluster using Terraform or many? Can you share your terraform resources?

Comment: Hello, I want to create my IT infrastructure with google provider, then using Kubernetes provider to apply some tools like kong, mongodb and other...